# Highcharts live graph setExtremes issue

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart with live data update, I use setInterval to add fake data and when data is received from ajax call I add or update the data point depending on if the timestamp exists or not on graph, as you can see in example even though columns are out of graph area the data length keeps increasing,

http://jsfiddle.net/3sf5kq78/1/

```
$(function () {
var minTime =  (new Date()).getTime();
var time_range = 20000;
var maxTime = minTime - time_range;


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#add').on('click', function(){

        updateDataPoints();

    });

    /**
    * Function to update data points, in real using using socket 
    */
    var updateDataPoints = function(){
        var data = chart.series[0].data;
        var updateCount=0;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        var row =  data[i];
        row.update(row.y+Math.random(1,5));
        updateCount++;
    }


        $('#updateCount').text(updateCount);
    }

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo:'container',
            type: 'column',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = 1;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);

                        var time =  ( (new Date()).getTime() );
                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes( time - time_range, time);

                        $('#count').text(series.data.length);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            max: minTime,
            min: maxTime

        },
        yAxis: {
            min:0,
            max:20,
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });
});
```

});

how can I limit the number of data points to only which are visible on graph (with using setExtremes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use series update and then slice data to keep the same length of serie.

```
load: function () {

                var series = this.series[0],
                    yData = series.yData,
                    y;

                setInterval(function () {
                    y = Math.random();
                    yData = series.yData;

                    yData.push(y);
                    series.yData = yData;
                    series.update({
                        data: yData.slice(1)
                    });

                }, 1000);
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/owk1Lere/2/